# Usage of ContainsKey method with a variable

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have a string variable which holds some value and I want to be able to check if that string exists in a dictionary as a key with its variable name.
For a clearer understanding as you can see in the following code;

```
        string searchDuration = "200";

        var response = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"searchDuration","200"},
            {"minRssi", "-70"},
            {"optionalFilter","NO_FILTERS_ACTIVE_SCANNING"},
            {"txPowerLevel","200"},
            {"peripheralId","123wrong"}
        };
```

I'm able to use ContainsKey method as following;

```
        if (response.ContainsKey("searchDuration"))
            if (searchDuration == pair.Value)
                isEqual = true;
```

But I don't(actually can't) use it this way because;

- I need to pass in every string variable dynamically, I can't write every variable name as a string to pass in to ConstainsKey method
- It only check values and there might be multiple values with "200", this situation gives me false results.
- I want to compare the value "200" only with related key which is "searchDuration", not with "txPowerLevel" which has the same value.

Is there a way to check whether a string variable exists as a key in a dictionary to compare it's value with dictionary members?

Comment: There are simple solutions to this, the question is why you would do this?

Comment: I have key-value pairs from a Http response as you can see from 'var response' and I have some json key-value pairs stored as variables. I want to check if those json values exist in the response with same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this approach:

```
string searchDuration = "200";

var response = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"searchDuration","200"},
    {"minRssi", "-70"},
    {"optionalFilter","NO_FILTERS_ACTIVE_SCANNING"},
    {"txPowerLevel","-16"},
    {"peripheralId","123wrong"}
};

var wasItThere = response.TryGetValue(nameof(searchDuration), out var value);
Console.WriteLine(wasItThere && (value == searchDuration));
```

`TryGetValue` is better than `ContainsKey` since it gets the value at the same time as checking whether the key is there.

`nameof` is used to convert the variable name to its string representation.

*I have explicitly **not** used `pair.Value` since that code in your original question strongly implies you are iterating through the `Dictionary`. This is not a good idea (performance wise).*

Answer (score 1):

If the variables you want to compare are all part of an object, then you can inspect that object with reflection and compare what is found inside the object with what is present in the Dictionary. Here is how:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new { searchDuration = "200", txPowerLevel = "100", other = "123"};

        var stringProperties = obj
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) && pi.GetGetMethod() != null)
            .Select(pi => new
            {
                Name = pi.Name,
                Value = pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(obj, null)}
            )
            .ToList();
        
        var response = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"searchDuration","200"},
            {"minRssi", "-70"},
            {"optionalFilter","NO_FILTERS_ACTIVE_SCANNING"},
            {"txPowerLevel","200"},
            {"peripheralId","123wrong"}
        };

        foreach (var item in stringProperties)
        {
            string v;
            response.TryGetValue(item.Name, out v);         
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ": obj value=" + item.Value + ", response value=" + (v ?? "--N/A--"));
        }
    }
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUNbRq

If the items are present as local variables then it can probably also be done (e.g. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbody.localvariables)), but I would recommend putting it in object to keep the values you want to inspect separate from other variables that your method needs and uses.